# .net crystal report export to stream from within sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web, crystal-reports, console-application

Good day,
 I currently have a crystal report within a console application. I use the following code snippet to get a byte array of the crystal report in pdf to be stored in a table in the database.

```
Stream stream = cryRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
 byte[] contents = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(contents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
 stream.Close();
```

This byte array is passed to a stored procedure which then inserts into a varbinary column in an sql server 2012 database table.

This might sound weird but can someone tell me if this can be done solely on sql server without a console app or web app?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using a [CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254963(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

You'll basically create a C# class library to expose your pdf conversion function to SQL Server directly. It will all run within SQL Server without requiring an external app.

Comment: do you have any tutorials or examples of this that you can point me to?

Comment: There a fair amount available on CLR integration basics. Split is a pretty classic example of a good use of the CLR and is shown here: http://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Article/246/CLR-Functions-in-SQL-Server-A-Tutorial.aspx.

Comment: I want to run a crystal report (produces an invoice with barcode font etc)  fully on sql server without a c# console application or web application, you are saying this is possible with CLR?

Comment: Yes. SQL CLR lets you take data form SQL Server, process it in a C# (or other) class library and return data back to SQL Server. You should be able to return your stream as SqlDbType.VarBinary.